# fetching records delay in performance using django

Tags: python, django, performance, postgresql

I am trying to fetch records and display it while clicking navigation link in django. Sometimes am getting **No Records Found**. But when i tried 3 to 4 attempts to click on then navigation link am getting records. How is it possible?? . I can't able to understand what problem is this? Could you please suggest any idea to solve this kind of performance issue.

Comment: You need to do some groundwork, enable logs, try to narrow it down, could be anything.

Comment: nothing i can see in the log..

Comment: Without code, traceback, and further detail, this question is essentially unanswerable.